# MySQL - Update siblings with same key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Couldn't find a solution yet... although it is probably a newbie question, I haven't been able to overcome... hope someone can give a hand.

I have a MySQL table that has:

> Blockquote

```
     Col1  Col2
Row1 A     null
Row2 A     A1
Row3 A     null
Row4 B     null
Row5 B     B1
etc

> Blockquote
```

How do I construct an SQL update to update Col2, so that the values on Col2 replace the null, ie, C2R1 and C2R3 gets A1, and C2R4 gets B1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the required values as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE yourtemptable AS
SELECT yourtable.col1, T1.col2
FROM yourtable
JOIN
(
    SELECT col1, MAX(col2) AS col2
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY col1
) T1
ON yourtable.col1 = T1.col1
```

You can then either drop/truncate the original table and recreate it using these values, or if you can't drop the table you can instead perform a multi-table [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked great. I then runned: 
`code`
    UPDATE temptable Inner Join kk
 ON temptable.col1 = kk.col1 
    SET kk.col2 = temptable.col2 
    Where
      ((temptable.col2 <> '') Or (temptable.col2 Is Not Null)) And
      ((kk.col2 = '') Or (kk.col2 Is Null))
`code`
It was terribly slow (my update, not the temp table that was very fast), but worked. Really thanks a lot. Will try to help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not work (because the MySQL documentation states that *Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*), you should try with something like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = (SELECT t2.col1 FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.col1 = table1.col1 AND NOT t2.col2 IS NULL LIMIT 1) WHERE table1.col2 IS NULL
```